# Why am I getting 0 for Series.prod()?

Tags: numpy, pandas, precision, multiplication, series

I have a series consisting of either positive numbers or nan. But when I compute the product, I get 0.

***Sample Output :***

```
    In [14]: pricerelatives.mean()
    Out[14]: 0.99110019490541013
    In [15]: pricerelatives.prod()
    Out[15]: 0.0
    In [16]: len(pricerelatives)
    Out[16]: 362698
    In [17]: (pricerelatives>0).sum()
    Out[17]: 223522
    In [18]: (pricerelatives.isnull()).sum()
    Out[18]: 139176
    In [19]: 223522+139176
    Out[19]: 362698
```

Why I am getting 0 for `pricerelatives.prod()`?

Update:
Thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately, it did not work:

```
    In [32]: import operator
    In [33]: from functools import reduce
    In [34]: lst = list(pricerelatives.fillna(1))
    In [35]: the_prod = reduce(operator.mul, lst)
    In [36]: the_prod
    Out[36]: 0.0
```

Explicitly getting rid of nulls also fails:

```
    In [37]: pricerelatives[pricerelatives.notnull()].prod()
    Out[37]: 0.0
```

Update 2:
Indeed, that's exactly what I just did and was going to add.

```
    In [39]: pricerelatives.describe()
    Out[39]: 
    count    223522.000000
    mean          0.991100
    std           0.088478
    min           0.116398
    25%           1.000000
    50%           1.000000
    75%           1.000000
    max          11.062591
    dtype: float64
```

Update 3: Still seems strange to me. So more detailed information:

```
    In [46]: pricerelatives[pricerelatives<1].describe()
    Out[46]: 
    count    50160.000000
    mean         0.922993
    std          0.083865
    min          0.116398
    25%          0.894997
    50%          0.951488
    75%          0.982058
    max          1.000000
    dtype: float64
```

Update 4: The ratio is right around your example's cutoff between 0 and >0 but my numbers are much more clustered around 1 than uniform 0,1 and uniform 1,2.

```
    In [52]: 50160./223522
    Out[52]: 0.2244074408783028
    In [53]: pricerelatives[pricerelatives>=1].describe()
    Out[53]: 
    count    173362.000000
    mean          1.010806
    std           0.079548
    min           1.000000
    25%           1.000000
    50%           1.000000
    75%           1.000000
    max          11.062591
    dtype: float64
    In [54]: pricerelatives[pricerelatives<1].prod()
    Out[54]: 0.0
```

Comment: Can you show `pricerelatives.describe()`?

Comment: Can you show `>=1` instead of `>1` in Update 3?

Comment: Also, compute the product of the the values < 1, and show that. That should be a very small number.

Comment: Why doesn't line 54 in your update 4 answer your question?

Comment: I suppose it does.  Many thanks!  BTW, I found a way to do my calculation.  I was computing the product so that I could get the geometric mean.  Instead of taking the product first, doing **1/n first solves the problem.

Comment: If you need to compute the geometric mean, use `scipy.stats.gmean`. This will be more numerically accurate than what you've suggested. I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a "bug" in `numpy`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2289076/564538). It doesn't raise when there's overflow.

Here are some examples:

```
In [26]: prod(poisson(10, size=30))
Out[26]: -2043494819862020096

In [46]: prod(randn(10000))
Out[46]: 0.0
```

You'll have to use the `long` (Python 2) or `int` (Python 3) type and reduce it using `reduce`/`functools.reduce`:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

lst = list(pricerelatives.dropna())
the_prod = reduce(operator.mul, lst)
```

**EDIT:** It's going to be faster to just remove all of the `NaN`s and *then* compute the product rather than setting them to 1 first.

Very informally, the reason you're still getting zero is that the product will approach zero faster as the ratio of the number of values in `[0, 1)` to values >= 1 grows.

```
def nnz_ratio(ratio, size=1000):
    n1 = ratio * size
    n2 = size - n1
    s1 = uniform(1, 2, size=n1)
    s2 = uniform(0, 1, size=n2)
    return Series(hstack((s1, s2)))

ratios = linspace(0.01, 1, 25)
ss = empty(len(ratios))

for i, ratio in enumerate(ratios):
    ss[i] = nnz_ratio(ratio).prod()

ss
```

gives:

```
array([  0.0000e+000,   0.0000e+000,   0.0000e+000,   0.0000e+000,
         0.0000e+000,   3.6846e-296,   2.6969e-280,   1.2799e-233,
         2.0497e-237,   4.9666e-209,   6.5059e-181,   9.8479e-171,
         7.7879e-125,   8.2696e-109,   9.3416e-087,   4.1574e-064,
         3.9266e-036,   4.1065e+004,   6.6814e+018,   7.1501e+040,
         6.2192e+070,   1.3523e+093,   1.0739e+110,   1.5646e+144,
         8.6361e+163])
```

**EDIT #2:**

If you're computing the geometric mean, use

```
from scipy.stats import gmean

gm = gmean(pricerelatives.dropna())
```